# How do I access the data in the nth column of DataTable?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, datatables

So I need to check the value of a specific column in a `DataTable`(The JQuery plugin). I am attempting to filter the table based on checkbox options but don't understand in which way the data for 'this' is organized. I've tried various multi index tests but get result that only confused me.

My data is a `JSON` file 'like' this:

```
var data = [{
    "Name": "John",
    "Size": "7",
    "Color": "BBB"
}, {
    "Name": "Bill",
    "Size": "5",
    "Color": "BBB"
},
   {"Name": "Tom", 
    "Size": "3",
    "Color": "BBB"
}]
```

And an example of how I am access column data

```
 table.rows().every(function() {
     console.log(this.data()[3]);
     //Or maybe?
     console.log(this.column(7).data());

 })
```

Comment: Have you checked the api for accessing column data? https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().data()

Comment: Yes, which is why I feel pretty dumb right now. Shouldn''t this.data() be the element from the JSON array? And this.column(3).data() be the value of the third element in the current JSON bbject?

Comment: I think you need to define the table like table = $("#YourDataTable").DataTable(); and then if you wanted the data in column 3 you would access that via table.column(3).data; or you could access the json data directly.

Comment: The table is defined in an anonymous in this fashion: var table= $('#table').DataTable(); I pass the table var along to the function that is processing it. Filtering the table with multiple settings is my end goal.

Comment: go for the last method ->  http://jsfiddle.net/w644Lgk9/